# neo4j shell logs doesn't have timestamp

Tags: java, logging, neo4j

So I have an enterprise version of neo4j 2.0 M3 on a linux server.  When I run neo4j-shell it logs the shell commands in my home directory.

Like so

```
ls -as
4 .                  4 .bash_logout    4 .groovy       4 .java           4 .ssh
4 ..                 4 .bash_profile      4 .emacs                4 .inputrc      4 .kde          4 .pki                                    
72 .bash_history      4 .bashrc            4 .grails               4 .ivy2         4 .mozilla      4 .shell_history
```

When we go into the shell history we just get a history of shell commands

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n,labels(n);
exit
START n=node(*) RETURN n,labels(n);
exit
```

However, it doesn't add a timestamp.  How can I have it add a timestamp.  I looked in `loggings.properties` but couldn't find it there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing my answer from the neo4j ML.

"That existed before, but were for some reason removed. I added a couple of standard bash prompt variables, and you can follow the process here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/907 (a pull request for to-be-released-later version 2.0)." Even the next milestone will likely contain it.

You'd use it for example like:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ export PS1="MyPrompt \d \t \W$ "
```

or specify it directly as an initial session value:

```
java <arguments for starting shell client> -DPS1="MyPrompt \d \t \W$ "
```